Does this inequality correspond to a general statistical property?
Let $\Theta$ be a random variable that is distributed on $\left[0,1\right]$ according to some cdf $\,\operatorname{F}$.

Does the inequality
$$
\left.\rule{0pt}{8mm}\mathbb{E}_F\left[\left(x-\Theta\right)^2\right]\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ \mathbb{E}_F[\Theta]} \leq \left.\rule{0pt}{8mm}\mathbb{E}_F\left[\left.\left(x - \Theta\right)^{2}\,\right\vert \Theta\geq x\right]\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ \mathbb{E}_F[\Theta]}
$$
correspond to some general statistical property ?.


It looks as if it is related to a type of skewness (though not the usual definition).  You might want to consider as examples: $\Theta_1$ with  $F_{\Theta_1}(x)=x^2$ and expectation $\frac23$ (left skewed and not satisfying your inequality), and then $\Theta_2=1-\Theta_1$ with $F_{\Theta_2}(x)=x(2-x)$ and expectation $\frac13$ (right skewed and satisfying your inequality).

Let $\mu:=\Bbb E(\Theta)$, so your inequality can be written
$$E[(\Theta-\mu)^2]\le E[(\Theta-\mu)^2\mid\Theta\ge\mu]={E[(\Theta-\mu)^2\,{\bf 1}_{\Theta\ge\mu}]\over P(\Theta\ge\mu)}
$$
or, rearranging,
$$E[(\Theta-\mu)^2]\cdot E[{\bf 1}_{\Theta\ge\mu}]\le E[(\Theta-\mu)^2\cdot {\bf 1}_{\Theta\ge\mu}]\tag{1}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$\text{cov}\left((\Theta-\mu)^2,\ {\bf 1}_{\Theta\ge\mu}\right)\ge 0
$$
i.e., $(\Theta-\mu)^2$ and ${\bf 1}_{\Theta\ge\mu}$ have nonnegative correlation.
NB: Intuitively, the above covariance will be negative if large values of $(\Theta-\mu)^2$ require $\Theta<\mu$, which suggests the following ...
Counterexample with negative correlation:
Letting $X:=\Theta-\mu$, so $X$ is distributed on $[-\mu,1-\mu]$, with $\Bbb E(X)=0$, the inequality can be written
$$\Bbb E( X^2) \le \Bbb E(X^2\mid X\ge 0)\tag{2}
$$
or
$$\text{cov}\left(X^2,\ {\bf 1}_{X\ge 0}\right)\ge 0
$$
which does not hold in the following counterexample:
Let $X$ have p.d.f.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
{1-\mu\over\mu}&\text{if $-\mu\le x\lt 0$}\\[1ex]
{\mu\over 1-\mu}&\text{if $0\le x\le 1-\mu$}\\[1ex]
0&\text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$
Then
$$\Bbb E(X^2) = {1\over3}\mu(1-\mu)$$
and
$$\Bbb E(X^2\mid X\ge 0) ={\Bbb E(X^2\,{\bf 1}_{X\ge 0})\over P(X\ge 0)}= {1\over3}(1-\mu)^2$$
giving
$$\text{cov}\left(X^2,\ {\bf 1}_{X\ge 0}\right) = {1\over3}\mu(1-\mu)(1-2\mu)
$$
so (in this example) Eq.(1) is violated whenever $\mu\gt{1\over2}.$

Thank you for your answer. I should have been more clear in my question. I understand that this inequality does not always hold. My question is rather whether there exists a well nown property of the cdf F s.t. the inequality holds.

@AlexanderJI I think that's about the same as asking whether the inequality itself is well-known, or has an equivalent well-known form. (Sorry, I could only recast it in terms of covariance/correlation. Of course, as I'm sure you realize, the LHS is just the variance of $\Theta$.)

Ok, thank you, that clarifies it!
